# Round php's number and and covert the rounded number?

Tags: php

Round php's number and and covert the rounded number?

```
$n = -5665.36;

->$new_n = round($n);

>>> $new_n =  -5665;
```

My Approach:

```
if($m=1)
  $p= $n;
if($m=10)
   $p = 5660
if($m=100)
   $p = 5600
if($m=1000)
   $p = 5000
```

Anybody know which php`math function` OR the `good ways` to do it use to get value of $p as expected here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$n = -5665.36;
$m = 100;
$precision =  -log10($m);
$p = abs($m == 1 ? $n : round($n, $precision) + $m);
echo $p;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
abs(intval($m/$round_set) * $round_set) //
```

if want to convert -ve to +ve. use `abs`  else need not to.

Comment: abs(round($m/$round_set) * $round_set), or else you are flooring the number instead of rounding

Comment: he wants floor. 5665/10 = 566.5 then round(566.5) will be 567. And 567 * 10 = 5670.  But he wants 5660